# When should I save data into SQLite entered into a fragment in my Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, events

I was watching one of Google's app reviews and they were ripping into this guys' app who had a save button and if you didn't save before leaving it would pop up a dialog.  They said an android app should just save and not bother the user.

I have a fragment and have several fields and need to determine when to save the data into a SQLite database.  I was thinking of saving on exit of each field via the `onFocusChange` event?  Or maybe that's too often?  Perhaps the fragment's `onPause` event?  When should I save (specific event please)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fragments` are much like the `activities` when it comes to lifecycle. So `onPause()` is the right place to save persistent state, later after `onPause()` it may be too late and can lead to data loss. Google recommends to use "edit in place" user model. That is, save edits immediately, in your case saving data when the user switches between input fields is good approach. This prevents data loss if your `Fragment`/`Activity` is killed by the system. If you think it can take few seconds to save your state you can use also `IntentService` in `onPause()`. In your scenario I would execute `AsyncTask` updating your database when the user switches between input fields, maybe with detecting if change really occured.

Edit: If you are using `ContentProvider` than consider using [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) instead of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Sounds good, thx :-)   I'll check for a change in on focuschange and save in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onDestroy()

Called when the fragment is no longer in use. This is called after onStop() and before onDetach().
```

I would probably use that; it would mean the user is done using that fragment. I don't know of any cons in doing it that way or your way.

Comment: Well with Activities at least there is no guarantee to get to onDestroy.  Is it the same with fragments?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It could very well be the same for fragments. I think when it comes to the user force closing apps and all that, there really isn't a best way to ensure a save. I guess the safest would be to save after each field is modified in any way.. though for a text view that would seem silly saving with each entered character. :P

Comment: yah, so what would the best field level event be to use...onFocusCHanged?

Comment: Yeah, or the respective callbacks for each field you use, so:
CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
        })  I forget the code is messy in here, sorry XD